# Latex command on 'cmd' is not finding my ".ins" file

Tags: templates, cmd, latex

I am having an issue to execute the file '.ins' for my article using latex command on the cmd prompt. It does not find the file.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: elsarticle is included in both texlive and miktex. You shouldn't have to install it manually, you can install it via your tex distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I was commiting a type mistake. "Elsearticle" instead og "Elsarticle". Now it is running. :-)